# LoginToBoggan and user registration password to allow users register with password and email verification at the same time

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

I am using the [LoginToBoggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module to enrich the account functionalities. In its settings there is a *Set password* field; when it's not checked anonymous users can't choose their passwords in registration form but they can receive verification emails.

I need both functionalities: email verification and set the password field in registration form.
I found the [User registration password](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_registrationpassword) module which allow users to choose password in the registration form.

The problem is when I create a new account. The user can login with the chosen password, but I need they first verify their email.

So the process must be like this:

- Anonymous users register and choose their password in the registration form
- They receive a verification email
- They click on the link given in the email to activate the account

The problems I have now are the following.

- Users can log in after registration, even if they didn't click on the link sent via email
- The link in the email is a kind of reset password link and not a link to verify the email link

Is there a possibility to fix this and allow users to choose their password in registration even if they still to verify the email they use for the site?

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://www.drupal.org/project/registration_role to auto assign a different role (as in other than authenticated) to users who register. 
https://www.drupal.org/project/autoassignrole this one offers a little bit more functionality.

Answer (score 0):

enable logintoboggan_rules module and import following rule

```
{ "rules_notify_user_when_account_activated" : {
    "LABEL" : "Notify user when account activated",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "logintoboggan_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "logintoboggan_validated" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "user_send_account_email" : { "account" : [ "account" ], "email_type" : "status_activated" } }
    ]
  }
}
```